# Result of sqlparameters.Add (or AddWithValue)

Tags: c#, sqlite

I'm trying to make a list of INSERT queries (to make faster transactions, but not all at once, in groups of 10 for example)
And then insert them (those 10 grouped before) at once. So I need to Add Parameters safely but cannot get the result sql-command. Is there a way to get this?

Currently I add items to the list with String.Format, but sometimes there are problems with single quotes. Below, string variables are singlequoted, others are integer or date. But some string variables have unexpected single-quotes in them (that's a mistake but users are for mistakes:). I can handle this with Replace("'","''") but I wonder if there's a more elegant way.

```
_csvalueslist += string.Format("({0},'{1}',{2},{3},{4},{5},{6},{7},'{8}','{9}','{10}',{11},'{12}','{13}','{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}',{19})$",
bina.KurumKodu, bina.KurumAdi, bina.mahKodu, bina.ParselID, bina.AdaNo, bina.ParselNo, bina.ATZeminID, bina.BagimsizBolumZeminRef, bina.BagimsizBolumNo, bina.Blok, bina.Kat, bina.BelgeID, bina.BelgeTarih, bina.BelgeSayi, bina.BelgeKonu, bina.BelgeAciklama, bina.BelgeTipRef, bina.BelgeTipAdi, bina.DosyaAdi, (int) durum);
```

Instead I want something like this;

```
_csvalueslist += sqlCmd.AddWithParameters("@KurumKodu",bina.KurumKodu).**GetCommand**()
```

Comment: dont use string format use $ as you can  see here [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated]

Comment: Have you considered `SqlBulkCopy`

Comment: I think i cannot use SqlBulkCopy, because my source is a csv file, and I do some other processing before writing into database.

Comment: I use $ interpolations everywhere but i could not get what you mean, does it have a better way of handling single quotes?

Comment: Put C# to one side. Let's say this was pure SQL. Show us an example of one of these list of queries with sample data in it.